# How does collision of electrons with other atoms generate heat that could result in release of additional electrons?

Tags: thermodynamics, solid-state-physics, electrons, electric-current, atomic-physics

How is heat generated by collision of electrons with other atoms. Pls explain without going into Joules law and it'd be great if you could provide me with an intuition